# Error when installing Tensorflowjs-gpu edition

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, installation, tensorflow.js

When I try to install @tensorflow/tfjs-gpu in node.js, I get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\tobia\2d-classification> npm i @tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\tobia\2d-classification\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node-gpu
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/install.js gpu download
npm ERR! GPU-windows-4.9.0.zip
npm ERR! https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-gpu-windows-x86_64-2.9.1.zip
npm ERR! * Downloading libtensorflow
npm ERR!
npm ERR! * Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings
npm ERR! symlink ./lib/napi-v9 failed:  Error: Command failed: node scripts/deps-stage.js symlink ./lib/napi-v9
npm ERR!   * Symlink of lib\napi-v9\tensorflow.dll failed, creating a copy on disk.
npm ERR! node:internal/process/promises:289
npm ERR!             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
npm ERR!             ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile 'C:\Users\tobia\2d-classification\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node-gpu\deps\lib\tensorflow.dll' -> 'C:\Users\tobia\2d-classification\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node-gpu\lib\napi-v9\tensorflow.dll'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4058,
npm ERR!   code: 'ENOENT',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'copyfile',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\tobia\\2d-classification\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node-gpu\\deps\\lib\\tensorflow.dll',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Users\\tobia\\2d-classification\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node-gpu\\lib\\napi-v9\\tensorflow.dll'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v20.5.0
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:421:12)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR!     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5) {
npm ERR!   code: 1,
npm ERR!   killed: false,
npm ERR!   signal: null,
npm ERR!   cmd: 'node scripts/deps-stage.js symlink ./lib/napi-v9'
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\tobia\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-22T13_17_27_507Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\tobia\2d-classification>
```

I did install @tensorflow/tfjs first as the official guide mentioned and I did also install cuda, copied the file in the cuDNN SDK and I also installed python.

I tried using windows cmd, vsc terminal, adding --force, ... pls help

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are using the latest version of Node.js and NPM. TensorFlow.js may have issues with outdated versions of Node.js
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file, and run npm install again to reinstall all dependencies:

```js
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
```

3. Check if you have the required dependencies for the GPU version of TensorFlow.js

If the problem persists, you can try installing the CPU version of TensorFlow.js (@tensorflow/tfjs-node) instead of the GPU version to see if this works:

```js
npm uninstall @tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu
npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node
```

Comment: So a) i just installed nodejs few days ago because this is my new laptop, b) i get the same error when installing @tensorflow/tfjs-node (cpu)... Do i really need python 3.6? I have 3.9 or so. @Gianmarco I am german btw

Comment: I just read that gpu version is only availible on linux ?! but at least the cpu version should work - which it doesnt

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the OP.  I can't install the CPU or GPU version.

Answer (score 0):

try to install specific version @tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu@1.2.4 or @2.2.4 for example